# Javascript form to array how do i remove List numbers from output

Tags: javascript, arrays, output

like the titles says I am trying to remove the list numbers from the beginning of my script output lines my script is below and and example of the out put I have and the output I want

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function textareaToArray(t){
return t.value.split(/[\n\r]+/);
}
function showArray(a){
var msg="";
for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++){
msg+=i+": "+a[i]+"\n";
}
alert(msg);
}
</script>
</head>
<title>
Welcome To ....
</title>
<body>
<center><h1> WELCOME TO .... </h1></center>
</br>
</br>
</br>
<center><form>
<textarea rows="7" cols="60" name="alpha"></textarea>
<br>
<input type="button"
value="show array"
onclick="showArray(textareaToArray(this.form.alpha ))">
</form></center>
</body>
</html>
```

exammlpe of current output

```
1. datadatadata
2. datadatadata
3. datadatadata
4. datadatadata
5. datadatadata
```

example of output I would like

```
datadatadata
datadatadata
datadatadata
datadatadata
datadatadata
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ummm...

Change: `msg+=i+": "+a[i]+"\n";`

to : `msg+= a[i]+"\n";`

Comment: I had a dangling `+` sign. I have updated, try again.

Comment: Perfect thankyou do you know any ways I can control the output like making executing a shell command with each line and output the data 1 by 1

Comment: okay let me rephrase that is there  a way I can get it to send each line to another webpage grab the result and echo the result line by line

Comment: you mean to send some string (which happens to be some shell command) from one webpage to another? if yes, then you are looking for [HTML5 WebSockets](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/websockets/basics/). Though I am not sure why would you want to do that.

Comment: what I would like to do for each line in my array output I would like to psts it to a php page as postdata wait for the php page to load then echo the result back . loop this over for each line in the array

Comment: forget the shell execute this is just another way I would like to do what I would like to echieve

Comment: I am not good in php. But pretty much in any web backend language like NodeJS / Rails / Php, you can have REST web services. You just need to write web services and utilize ajax calls.